# ionic v4 with angular - directive for input fields

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ionic4

I would like to create a function similar to the "`clearInput`" directive on the `ion-input` component, just with another icon and functionality :)

I had a directive that worked in ionic 3 but now it is outside of the shadow dom element and not rendered.

Would be nice if anybody could point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Ionic 4 provides `clearInput` by default.

Comment: I would like to have another functionality and another icon, it was just an example to clarify what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I just did a custom component with an input-field, an icon and some CSS for positioning.
Listening to the click event on the icon is used to trigger the desired function call.